# Is UTF-8 malleable?

Tags: validation, unicode

I've got two byte sequences, and I decode them as UTF-8 (in strict mode to be sure they're valid UTF-8).

Is it correct to assume that, if the bytes are different, the decoded codepoints will also be different?

In other words, is it possible to find 2 valid UTF-8 byte-sequences that decode to the same string?

Comment: i.e. I checked with the bytes `ed a0 bd ed b8 8a` (a surrogate pair encoded as UTF-8) and they're correctly identified as invalid... I also need to check how BOM is handled, and longer encodings of a codepoint

Answer (score 4):

> In other words, is it possible to find 2 valid UTF-8 sequences that decode to the same text?

Since a valid UTF-8 encoding has to be minimal by definition it is impossible to have two valid but different UTF-8 sequences which result in the same UTF-32 sequence.

But, this does not mean that different UTF-32 sequences are always a different "text" for some definition of text. Unicode has sometimes multiple ways to present the same character - see [Wikipedia: Unicode equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) and [Wikipedia: Duplicate characters in Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_characters_in_Unicode). And even if it is not the same character it might look the same - see [Wikipedia: Homoglyph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph).

Answer (score 3):

## Combining characters

You could write the character é as both

- U+00E9 LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE
- U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT + U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E

You could also have several combining characters provided in different order without that affecting the resulting character.

That's why you should do [Unicode normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) before attempting to compare two utf-8 byte sequences.

Comment: +1 Good catch, but those are still different strings (different codepoints), so they are not a problem. I am looking for distinct bytes that represent the same codepoints.

Comment: Also, I think you meant U+0301 instead of U+00B4.

Comment: Good point. U+00B4 is the standalone acute, in this context it would be U+0301. Edited.

Comment: @AlbaMendez: I'm nor sure what should be considered a problem. While this is an interesting question by itself, I think you have an ulterior reason (XY problem) which has not been shared. For instance, having two users, one called AlbaMéndez and the other AlbaMéndez that are actually different would _usually_ be problem.